# Stored procedure with user-defined table as parameter using EF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql

I need to pass a list of string to my stored procedure `Sp_Calculate_TimeSheet_Global_Info` So I created these two types :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Type_cmd] AS TABLE (
[TypeName] [varchar](50) NULL
)
GO
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Etape_cmd] AS TABLE (
[EtapeName] [varchar](50) NULL
)
GO
```

the signature of the stored procedure is the following :

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[Sp_Calculate_TimeSheet_Global_Info]
        @DateDebut = NULL,
        @DateFin = NULL,
        @UserId = NULL,
        @CA = NULL,
        @Client = NULL,
        @EtapeName = NULL,
        @TypeName = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

The problem is that when I used EF database first and i tried to get this procedure in the model

```
public virtual int Sp_Calculate_TimeSheet_Global_Info(Nullable<System.DateTime> dateDebut, Nullable<System.DateTime> dateFin, Nullable<int> userId, string cA, string client)
        {
            var dateDebutParameter = dateDebut.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("DateDebut", dateDebut) :
                new ObjectParameter("DateDebut", typeof(System.DateTime));

            var dateFinParameter = dateFin.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("DateFin", dateFin) :
                new ObjectParameter("DateFin", typeof(System.DateTime));

            var userIdParameter = userId.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("UserId", userId) :
                new ObjectParameter("UserId", typeof(int));

            var cAParameter = cA != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("CA", cA) :
                new ObjectParameter("CA", typeof(string));

            var clientParameter = client != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("Client", client) :
                new ObjectParameter("Client", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("Sp_Calculate_TimeSheet_Global_Info", dateDebutParameter, dateFinParameter, userIdParameter, cAParameter, clientParameter);
        }
```

the user-defined table are not recognized!!!

So I need to know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: I suppose they (table-valued parameters) are not supported by EF, and so you will have to execute your procedure manually.

Comment: @Evk how can I execute it manullay

Comment: [Using Table Valued Parameters in Entity Framework](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/78607b/using-table-valued-parameters-in-entity-framework/)

Comment: Just make regular query (using SqlCommand)